# How to increase space between edges (splines) and nodes in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, neato

I manually specified the starting position of every node and set splines=true.

The resulting image appears as follows:

[image: graph]

The spline between 1031 and 1028 appears to touch nodes 1030 and 1029. I am just wondering if there's a way to increase the margin here. I have tried specifying esep="+3,3" to give a very high margin around nodes but the same graph is still output.

Comment: Hm, that's very strange. Can you provide the sample file for the graph you've provided here, so we can poke around with it?

Answer (score 2):

As you're laying out the nodes by hand, why not [lay out the spline by hand](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k%3asplineType) as well with:

```
pos splineType
```

Splines are somewhat more complex to position than nodes, but not terribly so.

To get started, run your graph through `neato` with the output format set to 'dot' (`-Tdot`) and it will generate the lower-level layout.  Then you can adjust the coordinates for the problem spline.

Answer (score 0):

There are also [esep](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:esep) and [sep](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:sep) graph attributes.

From what I have observed, these attributes work very well when using neato to generate spline edges when positions are known. But, if set to a value that is too high, the output positions do not match the input positions, at all.

Answer (score 0):

**sep** & **esep** are graph-level, used to position all the nodes, but you are explicitly doing the positioning, so **sep* & **esep* will probably be ignored.
Instead, try adding one or more "duplicate" edges from 1031 to 1028, each in a different color, then make all the inner (too close) edges invisible.